# Java not recognized while trying to run selinium server

Tags: java, angularjs, protractor

I am trying to run the selinium webdriver manager for e2e testing on angular app but i get hit with the error -

> 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I know for a fact that java is configured on my machine, when i run java -version i get -

> java version "1.7.0_67"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: do u have JAVA_HOME environment variable?

Comment: Yes it is already set.

Comment: if so, it seems like the environment of the running batch does not have the same path... Please, edit it and see if there´s an overriding of the PATH variable and, if so, add the current: `PATH=%PATH%;whatever is defined in there`

Comment: Dont quite follow there, i am a bit of a java noob. How would i go about setting the environment path for the webdriver-manager start job? This path is supposed to be the same as the path for java home?

Comment: if in windows, type this in cmd window: `echo %PATH%`. There must be the `whateverpathtojavahome\bin` folder. Also, within the `.bat` file you´re using (if any) to launch the webdriver-manager, if there exists one line such as `SET PATH=whateverhere` it should be `SET PATH=%PATH%;whateverhere` in order for it not to lose the /bin reference in the PATH. It seems like, somehow, you can run java from the command line without it being in the PATH. Also, after editing the PATH in windows system settings, you have to close the cmd windows and open them again to refresh the environment.

Comment: Worked by adding the JRE path in the PATH variable. thanks!